# SignatureVerificationFailedException in WsFederationAuthenticationHandler with Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, federated-identity

I know very little about Azure and AD, so I need help. My users are logging on via the MS portal, the Azure control panel shows `success` against every log in users are being redirected to my auth sites 500 server error and this error is appearing in my logs.

```
System.IdentityModel.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
IsReadOnly = False,
Count = 1,
Clause[0] = X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(RawData = MIIC4[...]3KtWG1BLD...'. 
Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key. 

at System.IdentityModel.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ResolveSigningCredentials()
   at System.IdentityModel.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement()
   at System.IdentityModel.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions.SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionExtensions.ValidateToken(SecurityTokenHandlerCollection tokenHandlers, String securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation.WsFederationAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1f.MoveNext()
```

Why has this stopped work??? I really don't know what else to offer as a clue, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you config the multiple Federation partners(refer [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2009630.aspx?WSFederation+error+ID4037+when+configured+for+multiple+Federation+partners))? If not, did you write the custom code to verify the security token? I am testing ws-federation with the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation) and it works well for me.

Comment: If it had worked before, it may be that the key/certificate has expired.

Comment: Did you use the OWIN WS-Fed millderware to integrate with Azure AD? If yes, the signing key roll should be automatic( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-signing-key-rollover#owin)).